# How to upload & view json file to fetch its data later in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a small json and I want to use the data after upload it on my website

```
{
"Images" : {
    "url":
       [
        "https://images4.alphacoders.com/474/thumb-1920-47438.png",
        "https://images7.alphacoders.com/303/thumb-1920-303042.png"
       ]
   }
}
```

my problem is : when I upload the file.json, then I can only download it.

**Edit:**

To make my question more clear as requested, I upload json file in temp site

- https://sites.google.com/site/temp13948203/page1

Here the different when I try to use the json from my site and other sites such as [Myjson.com]

- https://sites.google.com/site/temp13948203/page1/file.json
- https://api.myjson.com/bins/s82gr

I can get the data from json only if I used the second link using this method (in ionic 3)

```
this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/s82gr").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.posts = data.images;
});
```

So, Is possible to get the json from the first link ?

Comment: Any helps guys! @Suraj Rao

Comment: I edited the question, you can check it now @Alon Eitan

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for similar thing a long time ago so don't remember what I searched but following is the sample which helped me so Try this code...

```
$.ajax({
      url: yourUrl,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: null,
      success: function (response) {
           console.log("RESULT:" + JSON.stringify(response));
           var json = JSON.parse(response);
      },
      error: function (response) {
           console.log("ERROR:" + JSON.stringify(response));
      }
 });
```